# Why is the selector with lower specificity being applied?

Tags: css, css-specificity

See the "Show" button underneath and to the right of "Open modal" on https://fresh-rfui-test.deno.dev/islands.

[image]

---

I have:

```
<button type="button" class="bg-neutral-50 px-2">Show</button>
```

and two stylesheets:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>fresh-rfui-test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rfui.deno.dev/rfui-v0-1-11.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <Component />
  </body>
</html>
```

`rfui-v0-1-11.css` comes before `styles.css`.

`styles.css` has:

```
[type=button],
[type=reset],
[type=submit],
button {
  -webkit-appearance:button;
  background-color:transparent;
  background-image:none
}
```

The `background-color` is being set to `transparent` because of this.

But `rfui-v0-1-11.css` has:

```
.bg-neutral-50 {
  --tw-bg-opacity:1;
  background-color:rgb(var(--color-neutral-50)/var(--tw-bg-opacity))
}
```

I don't understand why that selector doesn't take precedence and why it's value of `background-color` doesn't get applied.

---

Here's how I'm thinking about it.

- I refer to [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order) for the cascading order.
- For "1. Relevance", both selectors match the `<button>` and thus don't get filtered out.
- For "2. Origin and importance", they're both the same. Both have an origin of "author (developer)" and an importance of "normal".
- For "3. Specificity", `.bg-neutral-50` has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `[type=button]`. `0-1-0` vs `0-0-1`. So then, `.bg-neutral-50` should take precedence and have it's value for `background-color` applied.

Comment: Not lower specificity, but rather same specificity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you linked to say:

> CLASS column
>
> Includes class selectors, such as `.myClass`, attribute
> selectors like `[type="radio"]` and `[lang|="fr"]`, and pseudo-classes,
> such as `:hover`, `:nth-of-type(3n)`, and `:required`.

Both `.bg-neutral-50` and `[type=button]` fall into this category, so both of the selectors have specificity 0-1-0. This can be seen in Safari or Chrome dev tools by hovering on the selector:

[image] [image]

Comment: Oh! I see. Today I learned...